# Add another media viewpoint to my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline

I'm new at JavaScript and need some help. If the question is worded wrong, please change it to better fit my question.

I have a script that will change the URL based on the browser's width.

The code in my footer looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( window ).resize(function(ev) {
      var w=jQuery( window ).width();
      if(w>600){
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc')+"')")
        })
      }else{
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc')+"')")
        })
      }
    });
    jQuery(window).trigger('resize')
})
</script>
```

What the above code does is load `data-nsrc` until 600px, then `data-msrc` is loaded.

The `DIV` tag looks like this:

```
 <div data-nsrc="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'small-post', false )[0] ?>" data-msrc="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'mobile-img', false )[0] ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'small-post', false )[0] ?>')" class="img-right resimgsm">
```

My question is how do I add another media viewpoint to the JavaScript? I tried the example code listed below but it didn't change:

```
      if (w>768){
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-lsrc')+"')")
        })
      else if(w>600){
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc')+"')")
        })
      }else{
        jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
            jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc')+"')")
        })
      }
    });
```

And the `DIV` looks like:

```
<div data-lsrc="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'normal', false )[0] ?>" data-nsrc="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'small-post', false )[0] ?>" data-msrc="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'mobile-img', false )[0] ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'normal', false )[0] ?>')" class="resimgsm">
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would you not be better using media queries for this? - it seems like a lot of js for a display difference based on viewport size - which is the role of CSS media queries

Comment: Serving responsive images via inline CSS. My Theme is very complex and this is the best way to load responsive images with infinite scrolling. Only loads image based on browser's width. And yes, I'm also using CSS media queries.

Comment: And backwards compatibility as stock Android browsers don't support `<picture>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `if` doesn't have closing `}`

Try this:

```
if (w>768){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-lsrc')+"')")
    })
}else if(w>600){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc')+"')")
    })
}else{
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc')+"')")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Starting to understand JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You should write the conditions like this:

```
if (w>768){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-lsrc')+"')")
    })
}else if(w>600 && w<=768){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-nsrc')+"')")
    })
}else{
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.resimgsm'),function(i,el){
        jQuery(el).attr('style',"background-image: url('"+jQuery(el).attr('data-msrc')+"')")
    })
}
```

Note that I also fixed the brackets. Anyway this is what mediaqueries are for. Why do you need to use all this js to do the same?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Short answer is to server images responsively via inline CSS and backwards compatibility as some browsers don't support `<picture>` elements.